# Symfony2 Formbuilder select

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I got a FormBuilder in Symfony2 and a field like this:

```
$builder->add('branches', 'entity', array(
  'class' => 'BranchBundle:Branch',
  'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('b')
      ->andWhere('b.owner = :owner')
      ->setParameter('owner', $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser())
      ->addOrderBy('b.updated', 'ASC');
   },
   'expanded' => true,
   'multiple' => true
   ));
```

In my view I currently render it like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.branches, {'attr': {'class': 'selrow'}}) }}
```

My problem is: Symfony renders each branch as an own checkbox.

What I want to do: Render one select with each branch as an option. 
The output should be like this:

```
<select name="branches" name="createTask[branches][]" id="createTask_branches_1" class="selrow">
  <option class="cust_selectbox">Branch1</option>
  <option class="cust_selectbox">Branch2</option>
</select>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something here so please tell me if I have. You just want to render something that is currently a checkbox as a selection?

If so change:

```
   'expanded' => true,
   'multiple' => true
```

to

```
   'expanded' => false,
   'multiple' => false
```

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was missing. Kinda obvious but I just didn't see it.